# nr_periods from cpu.stat in cgroups on RHEL

Tags: cpu-usage, rhel, cgroups

I am trying to understand the `nr_periods` metric from `cpu.stat` inside `cpu` subsystem. From the docs:

> nr_periods — number of period intervals (as specified in cpu.cfs_period_us) that have elapsed.

The `cpu.cfs_period_us` is set to `200000`; and from the definition I expect `nr_periods` to monotonically increase with time.

So for 5 seconds, `nr_periods` should be `5000000/200000 = 25`

However, sometimes it doesn't increase and sometimes it does. Is this a bug or am I getting it wrong?

```
$ cat /cgroup/GROUP1/cpu.stat && sleep 5 && cat /cgroup/GROUP1/cpu.stat
nr_periods 129890
nr_throttled 24
throttled_time 25909422

nr_periods 129892
nr_throttled 24
throttled_time 25909422
```

**System Details:**

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

Thanks in advance.